# How to put css in MVC projects (vb!)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry my very poor english…

I'm migrating web form project to mvc and i have a lot of doubts. One of them is how to put css on mvc controls like textbox for example. How do that in visual basic? i only saw c# implementation and it seems working, but on vb don't:

ex:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtDate", Nothing, New { @class = "csstext" }) %>
<%= Html.TextBox("txtDate", Nothing, New { .@class = "csstext" }) %>
<%= Html.TextBox("txtDate", Nothing, New With { @class = "csstext" }) %>
<%= Html.TextBox("txtDate", Nothing, New With { .@class = "csstext" }) %>
```

all of the implementation above generate errors on compilation

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtDate", Nothing, New With { ._class = "csstext" }) %>
```

This implementation don't, but my css doesn't work!

And if i put like this: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate2" runat="server" CssClass="csstext" />`

Works!!

I appreciate if you could help me!

Thank you very much

Comment: "And if i put like this:

Works!!" Is there something missing from the middle there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtDate", Nothing, New With { .class = "csstext" }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Darin seems to answer your question (though I have little VB.NET knowledge), but I'd really suggest you to look at [FluentHtml](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/) from MvcContrib, where you can do

```
<%= this.TextBox("txtDate").Value(Nothing).Attr("class", "csstext") %>
```